# Flutter: why image_picker doesn't open the photos from my gallery?

Tags: flutter, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery

I'm new in Flutter and can't get image_picker to open a picture from gallery.

It opens Gallery, but when I tap on a picture, just close gallery

My code is like this.. what i'm missing?

```
File _imagenTemporal;      


var imagen; 

Future getImagen(String opcion) async {

if (opcion == "camara") {

    imagen = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

} else if (opcion == "galeria") {

    imagen = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

}


    setState(() {
      _imagenTemporal = imagen;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you pass opcion  i think the problem is within that

Comment: the option works good, y tried it and choose the correct option between camera and gallery, but i can't get to show the image fron neither of them.. I tried a more simple code to try but it doesn't work neither.. I posted it like and answer to show the new code i tried.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`ImagePicker` is just a `FileChooser` function that returns a `Future<File>` widget when the user selects a `File` from the gallery or takes a picture. You should use the returned file to construct an `Image.file` widget:

```
Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   child: showSelectedImage();
),

Future<Image> showSelectedImage() async {

   _imagenTemporal = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

   return Image.file(_imageTemporal);

}
```